# Swift/SceneKit - best practice to create menu / level select scenes for the game

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I'm quite new to iOS level development, currently trying to create my first SceneKit game - however, i'm not sure what approach should i use to create the "non-3D" pages like menu, level select page, settings etc.

I currently have one GameViewController, and i use empty SCNScene with overlaySKScene to display my SpriteKit menu. Upon clicking the play button in menu i transition to another empty SCNScene where i would like to display list of levels. Should i again use ovelaySKSCene, is this the correct approach?

I also noticed that even if i set scnView.overlaySKScene = nil before transitioning to levelScene , if i tap in the spot of the previous placement of pla button, the nodePressed in overlayScene still contains the playButton node..

Forgive me for the rookie questions, i haven't been able to find a good example of this type of scenarios so far to learn from.

My code so far:

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore
import SceneKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

var scnView: SCNView {
    let scnView = view as! SCNView
    scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(displayP3Red: 0.98, green: 0.64, blue: 0.04, alpha: 1)

    return scnView
}

var menuScene: SCNScene!
var levelsScene: SCNScene!

var ground: SCNNode!
var light: SCNNode!
var scnScene: SCNScene!
var cameraNode: SCNNode!
var brickNode: SCNNode!
var selectedBrickNode: SCNNode!
var bricksArray : [SCNNode] = []

var controls: SKScene!
var levels: SKScene!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupView()
    showMenu()
    setupCamera()
}


override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return true
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}



func setupView() {

    scnView.showsStatistics = true
    scnView.allowsCameraControl = false
    scnView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
}

func showMenu() {
    menuScene = SCNScene( )
    scnView.scene = menuScene
    self.controls = Controls(size: self.view.bounds.size)
    self.controls.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    scnView.overlaySKScene = self.controls

}

func showLevels(){
    levelsScene = SCNScene()

    self.levels = Levels(size: self.view.bounds.size)
    self.levels.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    scnView.overlaySKScene = self.levels

    let transition = SKTransition.push(with: .left, duration: 1.0)
    self.scnView.present(levelsScene
        , with: transition, incomingPointOfView: nil, completionHandler:nil)
}

func setupCamera(){
    cameraNode = SCNNode()
    let camera = SCNCamera()
    camera.zFar = 10000
    cameraNode.camera = camera
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 20)

    let constraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: ground)
    constraint.isGimbalLockEnabled = true
    cameraNode.constraints = [constraint]


    let ambientLight = SCNLight()
    ambientLight.color = UIColor.darkGray
    ambientLight.type = SCNLight.LightType.ambient
    cameraNode.light = ambientLight


    menuScene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    print("touch began  ")

    for touch: UITouch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: scnView.overlaySKScene!)
        let nodePressed = self.controls.atPoint(location)
        print(nodePressed.name)
        if (nodePressed.name == "playButton") {
            scnView.overlaySKScene = nil
            showLevels()
        }

    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“the nodePressed in overlayScene still contains the playButton node...”

You are setting the pointer to the overlay scene to nil, and in touchesbegan you get the location from the overlay scene but then you use atPoint on the skscene stored in the “controls” property, so it still finds the play button. So replace self.controls with scnView.overlaySKScene in touchesbegan.

That said, I don’t know what in general is considered best practice by others but personally, once I need more than just a couple of buttons, I stop using the spritekit overlay scene and instead use regular UIKit elements to build menus on top of the SCNView.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Xartec, much appreciated. Can you please clarify what do you mean by "UIKit elements on top of SCNView"?  At the end i decided to use storyboard to create other viewcontrollers and design my menu/level-select pages with UIKit elements and navigate in/out of the game controller with segues - is this similar to your approach?

Comment: What I do is create a UIView with the desired elements in a XIb file and then add it as a regular subview of the SCNView itself. So I can have a 3D scene as the background, and use regular UIKit elements on top of that. If the menu scene is entirely 2D then yes you should still avoid the overlaySKscene.